# How can I use a runtime variable, that is not known by typescript?

Tags: html, typescript

I need to use one global variable in typescript, that is defined at runtime.

I need this to transfer some config properties from server side language to javascript. I'm using typescript to generate my javascript files.

```html
<script>
var globalProperties = {foo: 'bar', phpName: 'phpValue'};
</script>
<script src="/compiledTypeScriptFile.js"></script>
```

How can i use my globalProperties in compiledTypeScriptFile.ts? The globalProperties are automatically generated. So I cannot put them in a seperate ts file or something like this.

Im not using any client side lib except for jQuery.

Please consider globalProperties as type `any[]`. The name value pairs will extend automatically in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just `declare` it:

```
declare var globalProperties: { [key: string]: any };
```